# UIRefreshControl not showing in landscape when in a navigation controller with large titles

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ios11, uirefreshcontrol

I have a plain `UITableViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController` which **prefers large titles**. I added a refresh control to my table view controller.

On iPhone in iOS 11, if I launch my app in portrait mode, switch to landscape and begin refreshing the table view, **the refresh control does not show up**. The refresh happens, but the control is just not present. It's not even in the view hierarchy:

[image: view hierarchy]

Note that the same **does** work on iPhone if I'm in portrait mode, and also on iPad in every orientation. **It also works on iOS 10** with every device and every orientation and **also works on iOS 11** if I disable large titles, so it obviously has something to do with the large titles.

Here is a screenshot from the same thing on iOS 10:

[image: screenshot of the refresh control on iOS 10]

[I made a sample project for this.](https://github.com/tamassengel/DisappearingRefreshControl) There is no code involved, here is the whole setup in Interface Builder:

[image: screenshot of setup]

The same thing happens when I try it with a simple `UIViewController` with an embedded `UITableView` or `UIScrollView`.

I'm pretty sure this is a bug. How can I make the refresh control visible on iPhone in landscape?

Comment: Can't reproduce from your example project. I see the refresh control in landscape when I pull down.

Comment: @matt What OS and device did you try it on?

Comment: OK, wait, I see now: it doesn't work in landscape _if_ you do it in portrait first.

Comment: I'd say this is a bug. If you turn off Prefers Large Titles everything is fine. I've played with some other settings, but no effect. Pls report this to Apple.

Comment: @matt Thank you, this is an important detail I've missed. I will edit my question.

Comment: Very good, I can reproduce the whole thing in a new project in just a few seconds.

Comment: anyone knows if this is tracked by apple ?

Comment: @RuiMarinho Yes, I reported the problem for them.

Comment: @TamásSengel have you heard anything back? Did Apple fix this yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We fixed this by recreating the refresh control on every rotation. It's called in viewDidLoad() too.

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

    if traitCollection.verticalSizeClass != previousTraitCollection?.verticalSizeClass {
        tableView.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl() // !!!
        tableView.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPullToRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
    }
}

@objc func didPullToRefresh() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { [weak self] in
        tableView.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If this workaround works, it should be the accepted answer rather than my answer!

Comment: There seems to be an issue with this workaround. If you rotate the device from landscape to portrait mode while refreshing is in progress, it seems to mess up the collectionView layout. It leaves a large gap at the top of the collectionView. I suppose the same happens with tableView

Answer (score 1):

This can clearly be characterized as a bug. It's readily reproduced. Your description seems quite correct; once you've exposed the refresh control in portrait and then rotated to landscape, the refresh control isn't even in the interface in landscape (that's easy to see if you give it a background color).

On the whole, however, this is not very surprising. There are many bugs connected with large titles; Apple clearly hasn't thought through this feature very carefully.